# Splitting a View into several files in Swing MVC

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, model-view-controller

My project follows the MVC pattern. To make it quick, I will only post the code relevant to my problem (which doesn't involve the Model). Explanations below.

**Controller.java** :

```
public class Controller {

    public View myView;

    public Controller() {
        myView = new myJFrame(this);
    }

    public void displayViews() {
        myView.display();
    }

    public void closeViews() {
        myView.close();
    }
}
```

**View.java** :

```
public abstract class View {

    private Controller controller;

    public View(Controller controller) {
        super();

        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public final Controller getController() {
        return controller;
    }

    public abstract void display();

    public abstract void close();
}
```

**myJFrame.java** :

```
public class myJFrame extends View {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JMenuBar myMenuBar;

    public myJFrame(Controller controller) {
        super(controller);
        buildFrame();
    }

    private void buildFrame() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        frame.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly. However, the `buildFrame()` method will soon become **huge** if I keep adding components, so I would like to split it and create a new class in a new file for every Swing component.

The problem is that I want my components to retain their access to the Controller. `myFrame` extends `View`, therefore the `getController()` method can be called anytime. But it is no longer the case when I create a separate file. Extending `View` doesn't seem to be an option (besides, `myMenuBar` already extends `JMenuBar`, for example).

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that I want my components to retain their access to the Controller.

Fine.  Create a class for the JPanels that make up your GUI, and pass an instance of View to each of them through their respective constructors.

You shouldn't extend Swing components unless you're overriding a component method.  You should use Swing components.

**Composition over inheritance**

You shouldn't be extending View either.  Passing an instance of the view is sufficient.

Read this excellent article, [Sudoku Solver Swing GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196), for a better idea of how to use the MVC pattern when constructing a Swing GUI.